# Python - find PID function using psutil - does not return anything

Tags: python, psutil

I have a function that should return the process ID of a given process using psutil, but for some reason it doesn't return anything.

Printing the required variable shows the correct value. I think I'm doing something wrong.

```
def pid_find(process_name):
   pid = []
   for proc in psutil.process_iter():
     try:
        if proc.name() == process_name:
            pid.append(proc.pid)
     except psutil.AccessDenied:
        pass
   try:
     process = pid[0]
   except IndexError:
     raise Exception("Process %s not found" % process_name)
   print process # prints the correct value
   return process # does not return anything
```

Comment: check if you are using proper indentions.....

Answer (score 1):

with proper indentions it should look like this -

```
def pid_find(process_name):
    pid = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name() == process_name:
                pid.append(proc.pid)
        except psutil.AccessDenied:
            pass
    try:
        process = pid[0]
    except IndexError:
        raise Exception("Process %s not found" % process_name)
    print process #prints the correct value
    return process # return value
```

Comment: yes, that is the indentation that I am using on my machine. I'm new to this site and I'm still learning proper formatting.sorry

Comment: Function is located in file "functions.py". This is how I call it from file "test.py":
import functions
functions.pid_find("chrome.exe")

Answer (score 0):

can be done with wmi query without iterations:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import wmi
server = Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
c = server.ConnectServer("localhost", "root\\cimv2")
process_query = "Select * from Win32_Process Where Namse like '%{0}%'".format(cmd_argument)
process = c.ExecQuery(process_query)
for i in process[0].Properties_:
    if i.Name == 'ProcessId':
        return i.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I just try and test your code. It's works, except this :

```
if proc.name() == process_name:
```

Must be replace by:

```
if proc.name == process_name:
```

With some simplification, but with your code spirit :

```
   import psutil

   def pid_find(process_name):
      for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
           if proc.name == process_name:
              return proc.pid
        except psutil.AccessDenied:
           pass
      raise Exception("Process %s not found" % process_name)

   print pid_find("bash")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. The function is working fine, but I was not debugging correctly to check if the function works:

This is how I tried:

Function is located in file **functions.py** file
I was calling the function in the **test.py** file like this:

```
import functions
def debug
   functions.pid_find("chrome.exe) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    debug()
```

But if I put the function into a variable, I should be able to store the result and use it further:

```
import functions
def debug(proc):
    pid = functions.pid_find(proc)
    print pid #shows that pid has the correct value
```